# initializing a union of structs

Tags: c++, c

```
struct EXMPL
{
  union
  {
    struct
    {
      struct 
      {
        uint8_t AA;
        uint8_t BB;
        uint8_t CC;
        uint8_t DD;
      }Rev;

      struct
      {
        uint8_t XX;
        uint8_t VV;
        uint8_t WW;
        uint8_t FF;
      }IDs;
    };

    struct UNN
    {
      uint32_t A;
      uint32_t B; 
    };
  };
};
```

When I attempt to initialize this like so:

```
EXMPL aStruct = {{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00 }, { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }};
```

I get a "too many initializer values" error. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which member of the union are you wanting to initialize? You can only use one at a time.

Comment: There is no instance of the `union`, `UNN` and the anonymous `struct` in your code. What's to initialize?

Comment: C or C++, it can't be both. In particular, in C you need to use `typedef` to be able to use the structure name as a type, but you don't need that in C++.

Comment: Do it right. Use a constructor in your `union`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C`, `EXMPL aStruct = {{...` needs to be `struct EXMPL aStruct = {{...`

2 levels of `{{` missing - added

```
int main(void) {
  struct EXMPL  // level 1
  {
    union  // level 2
    {
      struct // level 3
      {
        struct  // level 4
        {
          uint8_t AA;
          uint8_t BB;
          uint8_t CC;
          uint8_t DD;
        }Rev;

        struct
        {
          uint8_t XX;
          uint8_t VV;
          uint8_t WW;
          uint8_t FF;
        }IDs;
      } ;

      // level 3 
      // but irrelevant to initialization as only 1st union member counts by default
      struct UNN  
      {
        uint32_t A;
        uint32_t B;
      } ;
    };
  };

  struct EXMPL aStruct = {{{{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00 }, { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }}}};
  ...
```

Comment: Added bonus, once C++'s naming requirements are resolved, this will work in (guess what?) C++.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you get too many initializers error.  You are using too many initializers.  A union only holds exactly one of its members at any time.  Not two, not three, not nine.

You should also pick a language.  C and C++ are not the same by a long shot.  Unions have little place in most C++ programs.  They were next to useless until recently when the rules regarding what they could hold have changed, but there's still few cases when you really want or need a union.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the outer struct to one of the union members directly. 
You should set one of the members of the union inside *EXMPL*.

As a reference please follow this simple example.

Say I have this struct definition:

```
    struct unionExample {
      union{    
        int integerInUnion;
        long longInUnion;
      }
    }
```

If you want to set the union member to an int, you have to set it like this:

```
struct unionExample union_example;        
union_example.integerInUnion = 5;
```

Just to rectify what your error is, you are trying to set the union member like this:

```
union_example = 5
```

which of course you cannot do, since union_example is of type unionExample and not int.

Going back to the example you have posted, you need to name the first struct inside your union. I will be naming it *XYZ*. So the code will look like this:

```
 struct EXMPL
{
  union
  {
    struct XYZ
    {
      struct 
      {
        uint8_t AA;
        uint8_t BB;
        uint8_t CC;
        uint8_t DD;
      }Rev;

      struct
      {
        uint8_t XX;
        uint8_t VV;
        uint8_t WW;
        uint8_t FF;
      }IDs;
    };

    struct UNN
    {
      uint32_t A;
      uint32_t B; 
    };
  };
};
```

You shall now set the value of *XYZ* like so:

```
EXMPL aStruct;
aStruct.XYZ = {{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00 }, { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }};
```

Comment: A fairly complete answer to a different question. I'm guilty of this from time to time myself, so no downvote, but did you compile this?

Comment: No, I did not have the time to compile, but I just wanted to outline what the problem was in this case.

Comment: The problem is OP wanted a static initialization. Your answer uses an assignment. The compile problem is `aStruct.XYZ` says `aStruct` has a member named `XYZ`, and it doesn't. It has a structure named `XYZ`, but does not provide a name for that member. Not kosher in C++, but in C the fact that `XYZ` exists sort of drops out of the naming equation and you can access `aStruct.Rev` and `aStruct.IDs`.

Answer (score 1):

Can someone comment on the portability of designated initializers? In my opinion this is much clearer than however many nested brackets.

```
struct EXMPL aStruct = {
    .Rev = { 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x00 },
    .IDs = { 0x01, 0x10, 0x11, 0x00 }
};
```

Not to mention this allows directly initializing A and B if desired.

Comment: Designated initializersare in C++20 but not in previous C++ standards.